# How does DBCC CHECKDB use tempdb?

Tags: sql-server-2014, tempdb, dbcc-checkdb

I would like to know the working principle of DBCC regarding the tempdb. I want to know why it uses tempdb for what purpose. I didn't find any advanced article about that so maybe someone can shortly explain or at least share links for the article about that.

Comment: All you need to read is [Checkdb From Every Angle](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-complete-description-of-all-checkdb-stages/)

Comment: Thank. Great resourse